# Suitable thread "fence" for a worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, c++14

I have a Worker class that runs its own `thread` to do some work in parallel. During specific intervalls I want it to be idle. I have an interface

```
class Worker
{
    mutex m_wait;

    void pause() {
        m_wait.lock();
    }

    void continue() {
        m_wait.unlock();
    }

    static doWork(mutex& lock) {
        while(true) {
            {
                lock_guard _l(lock);
                // Lock and immidiatly unlock again
            }
            // Only *some* work
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see the `doWork` method checks once in a while if the mutex is locked (by `pause()`) and doesn't continue if that is.

---

I have some questions about this implementation regarding speed and alternatives:

- How much overhead is there from checking the `lock`? Suppose I make a matrix-multiplication of 10x10*10x10 in the real work (small datasets). then
- Is there an alternative, that achieves the same effect but has less overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cost of locking/unlocking a mutex depends on your platform and specific mutex implementation. In the best case locking/unlocking a mutex where there is no contention is equivalent of two interlocked memory operations.

In case of contention locking becomes a costly operation because most implementations will make a kernel call to wait for the mutex to unlock. However in that case you probably do not care as the whole point would be to stop the thread in the first place.

Comment: I measured it and when working on small dataset I can 1) combine multiple sets to a bulk and only stop after a bulk 2) drop the mutex before every iteration for one a few bulks. This gave me a speedup of 12x

Comment: 12x is a lot, what is the relative size of a set and a bulk? And what's your platform?

Comment: One set = one multiplication, one bulk = ~10000 sets, working on windows7 64